# Why isn't my slope calculator working?

Tags: ruby

```
puts "This is the Amazing Slope Calculator!!!!!"
puts "give me Two points (X1,Y1) and (X2,Y2)"
puts "What is X1?????"
A = gets.chomp.to_f
puts "What is Y1?"
B = gets.chomp.to_f
puts "What is X2?"
C = gets.chomp.to_f
puts "What is Y2?"
D = gets.chomp.to_f
Slope = (D - B)/(C - A).to_f
puts = "Comeon that is the easiest slope to find... It is 5!!!!!!!"
puts = "JK the slope is #{Slope}"
puts = "Have a good day"
```

It seems to take the inputs but never actually gives an output. I can't find any problems.

Comment: What inputs are you providing, what is it printing, and what did you expect instead?

Comment: Just remove the `=` after the last three `puts`...

Comment: BTW, `chomp` is superfluous when calling `to_f` or  `to_i`

Answer (score 1):

`puts` is a method and with `puts = something` you create a variable and override the name of the method. Three last lines should look like:

```
puts "Comeon that is the easiest slope to find... It is 5!!!!!!!"
puts "JK the slope is #{Slope}"
puts "Have a good day"
```

Also, you are using constants where you probably want to put variables. Uppercase names, like `A, B, Slope` are constants in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Also this code would probably fail if the points A and C are the same. Need to code in some sort of response when attempting to divide by 0.

An easy way to do this is to alter the existing code as shown below.

Slope = ((D - B)/(C - A).to_f) rescue "Cannot divide by 0"

What this will do is provide the statement "Cannot divide by 0" when the program eventually attempts to divide by 0. Instead of getting an error, there will be a nice print out!

Comment: This is not an answer. If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - From Review

Comment: I added my comment because I too was working on coding a slope calculator. My methodology was a little longer, but now that I've found a solution for the division by 0 issue I felt that I should share.

Comment: It still doesn't answer what the OP was asking.

Comment: But it is relevant to a functional slope calculator...I was only trying to add to the conversation by shedding light on an issue that the program still has. 

The previous answer covered the basics tenants of why the program wasn't working. This covers the possibility of 0 division, which will result in an error.